# EDBEngineError 'table is readonly'

Tags: sql-server, delphi, bde

I have 3 `TQueries`: `qy_master, qy_detail, qy_detail2`, master of `qy_detail2` is `qy_detail`, master of `qy_detail` is `qy_Master`, all queries have corresponding data-sources, I placed queries in datamodule, when datamodule create I activate those queries.

In another form I used those queries, when trying `'qy_detail.open'` it says `'EDbengine error : Tables is read-only'` but no problem when opening `qy_detail`, I don't modify SQL statements, but I don't know why this error happens.

I also tried with `qy_detail.Active := True`; this statement also raise error,

I used SQL Server 2005 connected via BDE and ODBC datasources.

Please anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set TQuery.RequestLive = true?  RequestLive is False by default forcing query to always return as read-only result set.

From [documentation](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa060199.htm):

> A TQuery can return two kinds of result sets: "live" as with TTable
>   component (users can edit data with data controls, and when a call to
>   Post occurs changes are sent to database), "read only" for display
>   purposes only. To request a live result set, set a query component's
>   RequestLive property to True...